# R - Derivative of Log Incomplete Gamma Function

Tags: r, gamma-function

The following functions are available in R:

- `gamma` to compute gamma function
- `digamma` to compute derivative of log gamma function
- `pgamma` to compute incomplete gamma function
- ? to compute derivative of log incomplete gamma function

I'm wonder what function can compute the derivative of log incomplete gamma function. I noticed the `gsl` package has a function `gamma_inc` but not sure how to compute the derivative of the log of this function.

If no function exists, is there a simple way to approximate this derivative in `R`?

Comment: the derivative of the incomplete gamma function `pgamma` is equivalent to the density function `dgamma`.  So you just want `dgamma(x)/pgamma(x)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, my comment and Ben Bolker's together give the answer.

I suggested the use of chain rule of derivation:

```
log(u(x))' = u'(x) / u(x)
```

then Ben pointed out that the derivative of `pgamma` (CDF) is just `dgamma` (PDF). So, we have

```
dgamma(x) / pgamma(x)
```

A properly defined function would be

```
f <- function (x, shape, rate) dgamma(x, shape, rate) / pgamma(x, shape, rate)
```